# Haskell function that takes one argument and prints a string to the output

Tags: haskell

I'm learning haskell now. 
Now i want to write a function which takes one argument(Int, for example), prints some string to the output and returns this argument. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
test :: Int -> Int
test h = do
         putStrLn "Here will be number!"
         h

main = print $ test 200
```

Now i getting such error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `m0 b0'
Expected type: m0 a0 -> m0 b0 -> Int
  Actual type: m0 a0 -> m0 b0 -> m0 b0
In a stmt of a 'do' block: h
In the expression:
  do { putStrLn "Here will be number!";
       h }
```

Is there way to implement what I want?

Comment: Note that technically there's something called `unsafePerformIO` that would allow you to do this with the signature you've given. But believe me you're better off forgetting it exists for the next couple of months, until you've got a better understanding of how Haskell works and exactly why you're not gonna be using that particular 'function' very often. Hint: It has something to do with the fact that it's not actually a function.

Comment: How can you get `h` *before* `putStrLn` in the error message when you've got `h` *after* `putStrLn` in the code?

Comment: @md2perpe edited(it was from my experiments with code)

Answer (score 4):

Since test produces output visible to the user, it must return an `IO Int`, not an `Int`.  Have a look at the [introduction to IO](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_IO) on the Haskell wiki.

Answer (score 0):

```
test :: Int -> IO ()
test n = putStrLn (show n)

main :: IO ()
main = test 200
```

Comment: Note that `test` = `print`.

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't seen `print` before.
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/System-IO.html#print